# Mechanize: form submit inside frame

Tags: python, forms, authentication, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm trying to login to a website using python and mechanize.

The website login form is inside a frame like below:

```
<frameset>
  <frame name="main" src="login.htm" scrolling="no" target="_top">
</frameset>

<noframes>
<body>

<p>This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.</p>

</body>
</noframes>
```

```
>>> br.open('http://example.com/')
>>> print br.form
None
>>> print br.links()
()
```

I'm not able to get the login form. How should I go about this?

Note: I don't want to directly open the link `http://example.com/login.htm`. It has to be via getting inside frame only.

Comment: @furas Please read the _Note_ in my question. As I mentioned, I don't want to open the URL directly because it is likely to change.

Comment: normally web browser loads frame using second request - so you wil have to do separated request too.

Comment: How should I do it? Can you help?

Comment: I never did it but I would try to use second `Browser` to open `http://example.com/login.htm` and I would use `CookieJar` to get cookies from first `Browser` and use with second `Browser`.

Comment: If you add real url in question then people can see problem and test it to create solution. Real url really helps.

Comment: But the question is How do you get `http://example.com/login.htm` from the frame?

Comment: @furas BTW, the real URL is - `http://203.192.212.233:8085/capexweb/capexweb/`. If you open it, you'll find the login form within a frame.

Comment: I see page and there is frame with `http://203.192.212.233:8085/capexweb/capexweb/capexmain_middle.htm`. When I get url from frame and open it in new window then I see also this frame - did you try to login in browser using only `http://203.192.212.233:8085/capexweb/capexweb/capexmain_middle.htm` ? Maybe it will work and you don't need `http://203.192.212.233:8085/capexweb/capexweb/`

Comment: page doesn't use any JavaScript or cookies so difference can be only header `Referer: 
http://203.192.212.233:8085/capexweb/capexweb/` so you can try to open directly url from frame using header "Referer"

Comment: BTW: when I tried to copy link `http://203.192.212.233:8085/capexweb/capexweb/capexmain_middle.htm` and open in browser then it converted some chars to entiites `midd‌%E2%80%8Ble.htm` - it looks like there are some strange chars. after rewriting word `middle`  manually I can open correctly page.

Comment: @furas: As I mentioned in my Note, I don't want to open `http://203.192.212.233:8085/capexweb/capexweb/capexmain_midd‌​le.htm` directly. Because it can change. I want to simulate the browser thing and want to open it by clicking on it only.

Comment: and the reason for `midd‌%E2%80%8Ble.htm` might be an error in copying the URL. As you said, it opens when typed manually. Hence, ignore this. We should only focus on getting the frame object OR URL somehow programmatically.

Comment: maybe you should use `Selenium` which will use real browser.